# SprinMVC Control flows

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to rewrite servlet control flow in Spring MVC this is my 
doGet in Servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        String path = request.getParameter("path");

        if (path != null && path.equals("register")) {
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/system/registeruser.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
        } else if (path != null && path.equals("usermang")) {
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/system/manageuser.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
        }

    else {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.print("Served at: " + request.getContextPath());
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/system/index.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

I want to convert the doGET above to Spring RequestMapping using Model and view 
Example

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/grcon" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getGrcon()

        ModelAndView modegeron = new ModelAndView("index");

if (path != null && path.equals("register")) {
      view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/system/registeruser.jsp");

        return modegeron;

    }
}
```

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are trying to do, because neither the headline nor the description asks any question. In Spring MVC there is a readymade servlet called DispatcherServlet, which you should use. The logic is handled by controllers.

Comment: Please go through the Spring MVC document. Some blog links which will be usefull http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/ . you should be able to get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it way to complex, use the power of spring to handle the complexities for you.

For starters add an `InternalResourceViewResolver` to your configuration, this will handle the view to resource translation.

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/system/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Next add a [`params`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--) element to your [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) to have a further specification of the mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/grcon", method = RequestMethod.GET, params="path=register")
public String register() {
    return "registeruser";
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/grcon", method = RequestMethod.GET, params="path= usermang")
public String manageUser() {
    return "manageuser";
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/grcon", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

Or use a method that has a `@RequestParam` and return the appropriate view. Small tip when doing `String` compare put the static value first, saves you a `null` check.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/grcon", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(@RequestParam(value="path", required=false) String path) {
    if ("register".equals(path) ) {
        return "registeruser";
    } else if ("usermang".equals(path)) {
        return "manageuser";
    }
    return "index";
}
```

However generally you also want to do some preparation of the `Model` so the first might be more applicable.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/grcon/{path}" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getGrcon(@PathParam String path)

    ModelAndView modegeron = null;

    if (path != null && path.equals("register")) {
       modegeron = new ModelAndView("registeruser");
    } else if (path != null && path.equals("usermang") {
       modegeron = new ModelAndView("manageuser");
    } else {
       modegeron = new ModelAndView("index");
    }

    return modegeron;
}
```